# How to switch two values in an NSDictionary in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have an `NSDictionary` with two values. Now I want to switch the values.  Here is my code:

```
NSDictionary *aDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
[aDictionary setValue:@"theValue1" forKey:@"theKey1"];
[aDictionary setValue:@"theValue2" forKey:@"theKey2"];

NSString *tmpValue = [aDictionary objectForKey:@"theKey1"];
[aDictionary setValue:[myDict objectForKey:@"theKey2"] forKey:@"theKey1"];
[aDictionary setValue:tmpValue forKey:[myDict objectForKey:@"theKey2"]];
NSLog(@"%@", myDict); 


//output
theKey1 = theValue2;
theKey2 = theValue2;
theValue2 = theValue1;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other than a couple of larger problems (you should be using `NSMutableDictionary` instead of `NSDictionary` if you want to change things, and you should use the `setObject:forKey:` method instead of the `setValue:forKey:` method), the root of your problem is this line:

```
[aDictionary setValue:tmpValue forKey:[myDict objectForKey:@"theKey2"]];
```

Think about what key you're setting.

Comment: got it man. Thank you. I must have been staring at the screen for too long